# Sobreescribir un archivo local con el contenido que tiene en el repositorio de origen

Tags: git

Quiero obtener el contenido del origen de un archivo para sobre escribir mis cambios locales. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo desde la consola de git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me imagino que quieres sobre-escribir tus cambios por algun error o algo asi, si no hiciste `commit` aun hay esperanzas xD. Hace un

```
git checkout tu_branch la_ruta_de_tu_archivo
```

Si quieres bajar tal cual esta el archivo desde tu repositorio, haz un

```
git pull origin tu_branch
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que también funciona haciendo `git checkout origin/master` [nombre del archivo]

Comment: @AndreFontaine asi es! , de hecho es mucho mejor que agregues el branch, voy a actualizar de todas formas para que no se preste para confusiones

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono esto. Nada mas tengo  la rama master.

```
git checkout la_ruta_de_tu_archivo
```